# No refresh on submit

Tags: html, forms, submit, refresh, onsubmit

I've got a site with a form.

The value of the input should be a specific value. This works:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var val1 = $("#teller").val();
    var val2 = $("#noemer").val();
    if (val1 == 3 && val2 == 10)
        alert("Goed gedaan! je hebt de vraag goed beantwoord. Je kunt verder met je avontuur!");
    else
        alert("Helaas... Dit is niet het goede antwoord. Probeer het nog eens!");
});
```

But when I submit the page will refresh, change my url and refresh the page so the page starts at the beginning again... This is the site: http://stilld.nl/brrreuk/

I don't want this to happen. I want the code to check if the value's given are correct, but then I want the site to stay where it is.

Hope you can help.

this is the html:

```
<form id="form_1">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="input_required" id="teller" name="teller" maxlength="2" class="valid" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" placeholder="?" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '?'">
            <label for="teller"></label>
        </p>
        <hr noshade size=3>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="input_required" id="noemer" name="noemer" maxlength="2" class="valid" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" placeholder="?" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '?'">
            <label for="noemer"></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button class="submit" type="submit" value="controleer">Controleer</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Change the type to button. Submit implies that you want to submit your form, but you're not submitting a form. Instead you're handling a button click. You can get rid of the form tags altogether.

Comment: Simple, but awesome. Post it as an answer and I accept your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Simply change the `submit` to a `button`.

The JavaScript:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var val1 = $("#teller").val();
    var val2 = $("#noemer").val();
    if(val1 == 3 && val2 == 10)
        alert("Goed gedaan! je hebt de vraag goed beantwoord. Je kunt verder met je avontuur!");
    else
        alert("Helaas... Dit is niet het goede antwoord. Probeer het nog eens!");
});
```

And the HTML

```
<p>
    <input type="text" class="input_required" id="teller" name="teller" maxlength="2" class="valid" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" placeholder="?" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '?'">       
    <label for="teller"> </label>
</p>
        <hr noshade size=3>
<p>
    <input type="text" class="input_required" id="noemer" name="noemer" maxlength="2" class="valid" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" placeholder="?" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '?'">       
    <label for="noemer"> </label>
</p>
<p>
    <button type="button" value="controleer"> Controleer </button>
</p>
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest *not* having a `submit` control (whether it's an `input` or a `button`. Your form will not submit it's input without it. You shouldn't make your form rely on JavaScript to simply submit.

Comment: @AymanSafadi I got rid of the form. He wasn't trying to submit. That was the problem. He just wanted his `onClick` handler called.

Answer (score 0):

List to the form's `submit` event instead of the button's `click` event:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do stuff
    // $(this).trigger('submit') if everything's ok
});
```

> **NOTE:** The `e.preventDefault();` line is important!